# How to check duplicate before adding to array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

1. hi, I got code, what can check duplicate when two same values are **ALREADY** in the list. How can I check duplicate **before** adding the second same value to list. ps. I'm coparing string values.

   ```
   var vals = $scope.todoDatat.map(function(item){ return item.time });
               var isDuplicate = vals.some(function (item, idx) {
                   return vals.indexOf(item) !== idx;
               });


               if (isDuplicate) {

                   $scope.errortext = 'time is a duplicate';

               } else{

                   $scope.todoDatat.push({date: day, time: time, value: 15, arvo: arvosi});

               }
   ```
2. When it founds a duplicate, it dont let me continue adding new values, that are **not** duplicates to the list. How can i continue add new values to the list, even when duplicate has found?

Thx beforehand =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound you looking for a solution like this:

```
        $scope.todoItems = ['13:00', '14:00', '15:00'];
        $scope.todoDatat = ['14:00', '22:00'];

        angular.forEach($scope.todoItems, function (item) {
            if ($scope.todoDatat.map(function (x) {return x;}).indexOf(item) >= 0) {
                console.log('Duplicate!');
                // $scope.errortext = 'time is a duplicate';
            } else {
                console.log('Not Duplicate');
                // $scope.todoDatat.push({date: day, time: time, value: 15, arvo: arvosi});
            }
        });
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a normal object and check if a key exists with JavaScript's hasOwnProperty?

```
var x = {};  
x['key'] = 'val';  
x.hasOwnProperty('key'); // true //  
x.hasOwnProperty('key2'); // false //
```

And here is a more advanced use case:

```
var x = {};
var prefix = 'item_';  
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
   x[prefix+i] = 'value '+(i+1);
}  
x.hasOwnProperty('item_6'); // true //       
x.hasOwnProperty('other key'); // false //
```

Removing items can be done like this:

```
delete x['key'];
```